# Cant access LicenseType field on $Profile in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

The [flow documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_resources_global_variables.htm&type=5) specifically calls out using the $Profile global variable to get the licenseType

> References information from the current user’s profile, such as license type or name.

However, if I use a formula to display `TEXT({!$Profile.LicenseType})` in a flow screen, it is blank when i run the flow.

I can access $Profile.Name and $Profile.UserType, but not $Profile.LicenseType

[image: screenshot]

On the [Visualforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_profile.htm) for $Profile, it specifically calls out that visualforce pages cannot access LicenseType and UserType

> Note that you can’t use the following $Profile values in Visualforce:
>   LicenseType
>   UserType

As screen flows run on the visual.force.com domain, perhaps screen flows cannot access $Profile.LicenseType?  But I am able to access UserType.

I have tried this when logged in as a user with a custom profile, in case its something to do with standard profiles.

Or is there something else I am missing?

UPDATE

tested screen flow in system mode : same results

tested autolaunched flow in system mode : same results